# Please help me identify this ATI graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, graphics

I have an ATI Graphics board and its power supply - not mounted in a computer.  I can't find a current model # on the internet.  All the board has is ATI in a large Chrome X covering the heat sink and the fan.  There is a number 638B3 on a sticker but that doesn't correspond to any model number sequence I found on the web.  There is also a sticker with D33A27 on the circuit board.  Can anyone help with a model # or an idea of where I can find a driver (which I need to match by Mod #) for this board?

Comment: Post Pictures Please.

Comment: Put it in a computer, boot off a live Linux CD and type `lspci | grep VGA` on the console to get the video card model.

Comment: What connectors it has, how big it is, colors, shape etc would help as well.

Comment: The D33A27 hints at a Radeon X600 SE or similar card from that line/era of cards.

Comment: Without more information we would be making wild guesses

Comment: This question is Too Localized.

Comment: If this is a windows system, speccy or gpu-z (both freewares) should detect you gpu specs. I suggest speccy as it is easier to find a download link that doesn't come bundled with adware one needs to carefully refuse during install. Unfortunately, neither has a Linux version (but I think Mac ones).

Answer (score 5):

Put it in a computer, boot off a live Linux CD and type `lspci | grep VGA` on the console to get the video card model.

Alternatively, remove the heatsink and fan, and look up the identifying information printed on the GPU chip.

Comment: This is the best answer with the amount of information given.

Answer (score 0):

Rob's answer is best given the current information. This one is just to show the era of the card is likely the X1??? cards. Below is an X1950 XT which has a chrome X. Guessing the lower end cards would skip this embellishment to keep costs lower.

[image]